# How can i limit the packet size when i am capturing with Tshark using command line

Tags: wireshark

currently my command is tshark.exe -i (int interface) -V -x -w C:\file.pcap but i cannot find  what i am supposed to add in order to limit the packet size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option [-s capture snaplen](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

```
-s capture snaplen
    Set the default snapshot length to use when capturing live data. No more than snaplen bytes of each network packet will be read into memory, or saved to disk. A value of 0 specifies a snapshot length of 65535, so that the full packet is captured; this is the default.
    This option can occur multiple times. If used before the first occurrence of the -i option, it sets the default snapshot length. If used after an -i option, it sets the snapshot length for the interface specified by the last -i option occurring before this option. If the snapshot length is not set specifically, the default snapshot length is used if provided.
```